# Is there a unit testing framework for testing PowerShell with PowerShell scripts?

Tags: unit-testing, powershell

I am lookin for a unit testing framework of type xUnit that lets me test PowerShell functions with PowerShell scripts.

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940497/how-to-do-tdd-and-unit-testing-in-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also found PSUnit on Codeplex. [PSUnit PowerShell Unit Testing Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/psunit)

There are some cool screen shots and a release is expected in August this year.

Answer (score 7):

Well, just for completeness: There is actually [PSUnit](http://code.google.com/p/psunit/). Doesn't seem to be very mature, though as I see only two spikes of activity since its beginning as well as no documentation to speak of.

But as I learnt from [cuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/), unit testing is something that fits into a very small space (at least for C in that case), so having something that works might not require too much effort.

Comment: It seems PsUnit started moving http://www.codeplex.com/PSUnit

Answer (score 4):

While not an actual framework a la xUnit, Lee Holmes did write [an article about how to unit test PowerShell using PowerShell scripts](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2005/09/05/unit-testing-in-powershell-a-link-parser/).

Answer (score 2):

From the project page for [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester):

> Pester provides a framework for running unit tests to execute and
>   validate PowerShell commands from within PowerShell.