# Is there a unit-test framework for Windows batch files?

Tags: unit-testing, batch-file, automated-tests

I need just something very simple like "run this command and succeed if there is 'this string' somewhere in the console output, fail otherwise". Is there such a tool?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940497/how-to-do-tdd-and-unit-testing-in-powershell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but you can easily write one in another batch script.

```
call TestBatchScript.cmd > console_output.txt
findstr /C:"this string" console_output.txt
```

will set %errorlevel% to zero if the string is found, and nonzero if the string is absent.  You can then test that with `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :fail` and execute whatever code you want after the `:fail` label.

If you want compact evaluation of several such strings, you can use the || syntax:

```
call TestBatchScript.cmd > console_output.txt
findstr /C:"teststring1" console_output.txt || goto :fail
findstr /C:"teststring2" console_output.txt || goto :fail
findstr /C:"teststring3" console_output.txt || goto :fail
findstr /C:"teststring4" console_output.txt || goto :fail
goto :eof

:fail
echo You Suck!
goto :eof
```

Or, you can go even further and read the list of strings from a file

```
call TestBatchScript.cmd > console_output.txt
set success=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (teststrings.txt) do findstr /C:"%%a" console_output.txt || call :fail %%a
if %success% NEQ 1 echo You Suck!
goto :eof

:fail
echo Didn't find string "%*"
set success=0
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

The below mentioned repo has been deleted and is unfortunately no longer available.

<strike>I have created a library for windows batch unit testing. It is currently in its infancy, but it works and I use it.</strike>

It is called cmdUnit and it can be downloaded from the project site on bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/percipio/cmdunit

Answer (score 2):

I use the following for [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)) type commands:

For batch file `foo.cmd`, create the following files:

`foo.in.txt`:
hello

`foo.expected.txt`:
hello world

`foo.test.cmd`:

```
@echo off

echo Testing foo.cmd ^< foo.in.txt ^> foo.out.txt

call foo.cmd < foo.in.txt > foo.out.txt || exit /b 1

:: fc compares the output and the expected output files:
call fc foo.out.txt foo.expected.txt || exit /b 1

exit /b 0
```

Then run `foo.test.cmd`