# Unit Testing frameworks for Powershell

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, psunit, pester

There was a question asked 3 years ago about Powershell Unit Testing Frameworks, [How to do TDD and unit testing in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940497/how-to-do-tdd-and-unit-testing-in-powershell), and all the frameworks were quite new at that moment:

- PSUnit: http://www.psunit.org/
- Pester: https://github.com/scottmuc/Pester
- PowerSpec: at github /shishkin/PowerSpec

After 3 years I suppose they've evolved and get mature. Now I would like to do TDD (never done before) and I don't know which one to use. Searching on Internet, it looks like PSUnit and Pester are the most used.

Are you using them? Which are the pros and cons of each of them? Any recomendation?

Thanks,

Comment: Smells like a discussion/opinion driven question to me. At the least I would suggest making it a community wiki.