# Is there any unit-testing library, modules etc. available for Powershell?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do TDD and unit testing in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940497/how-to-do-tdd-and-unit-testing-in-powershell)

Is there any unit-testing library, modules etc. available for Powershell?

(Or as Powershell is built on top of .NET, do people use Debug.Assert approach somehow?)

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940497/how-to-do-tdd-and-unit-testing-in-powershell

Comment: https://github.com/pester/Pester